HELP, did i get scammed?
https://etherscan.io/address/0x3c2d325fb064efeb049f0b11d2340302933b181a
Did i get scammed thru a smart contract?
https://pastebin.com/raw/x3Jtbd3T
ITPro Insider youtuber guide. Most likely i got scammed yeah
